# I do not understand inflate method and how this code save memory

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I still do not understand this code.

They say when the  ListView is not being used, the list view will be set it invisible to save memory.

```
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
```

First, I don't know what the inflate method is for. On the other hand, it looks like the code from above looks like when the listItemView is invisible or not being used, 
make the ListItemView appear or visible. If the android app does this, it will appear all the list item view which is not being used and run out all the memory. this is contradictory the idea of saving memory.

Comment: I think you are mostly confused how a ListView will "recycle" views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

God, I'm a bit rusty with Android now that I'm busy with JavaEE and Oracle. Well, here goes nothing.

If my memory doesn't fail me, that `inflate` method is supposed to parse the UI layout saved as `layout_list_item` and make a `View` object out of it that can actually be used.

About what you heard... I think you might have misunderstood. Making containers invisible, as you say, definitely won't save any memory at all. What Android probably does is: it creates as many containers as there are going to be displayed at the same time on screen, and then swaps their contents when they get scrolled out so they can be put below and reused. For instance, only 8 to 10 containers are used to display, let's say, 100 or more actual items inside a `ListView`. You end with about 110 objects in memory instead of 200, I can see some RAM being saved there.

This is a known good practice, and I'm pretty sure Android is not the only platform that takes advantage of it. [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/) does it too, by the way.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English, but thx for answering. I just don't know how this code saves memory.

Comment: You're not alone in this thing of "sorry mister, English not be my first language", so don't worry. Now, about what you're asking... you might need to see the whole context in order to notice it, but this `convertView` is being provided by Android in advance if it found a component out of screen that can be reused. If it didn't find any (so the object is null), you have to create (`inflate()`) one by yourself before using it. That's why the nullchecking `if` is in there. In the end, the less objects you create, the less memory you need, and the more you save.

Answer (score 0):

> First, I don't know what the inflate method is for.

The inflate() method read an XML layout file and creates Java objects for the UI elements to display on the screen.

> On the other hand, it looks like the code...

I do not understand this part of your question. There are two things happening here

1. Say you have a list view with 100 items but only enough screen space to display 10 at a time. Android only creates views for the 10 which are visible which saves memory by not creating all 100 views.
2. When the user scrolls down, Android reuses the view which disappears off the top of the screen for the view that comes up from the bottom of the screen. In other words, Android does not create new view objects as they scroll onto the screen. This reduces the amount of work that the garbage collector must do which requires CPU cycles. `convertView` is the view to reuse. If this reference variable is null, then there is no reusable view so e must create a new one by inflating the XML layout resource.

The code you gave might be easier to understand in a different form:

```
View listItemView;
if (convertView == null) {
    listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
} else {
    listItemView = convertView;
}
```

Now it is clear that we are checking if the given `convertView` is null. If so, then we must inflate a new view. If not then we can reuse the existing view. The original code in your question is equivalent.

Comment: Thank You for answering. I have asked the same question in Reddit. Their answer is as same as you. It seems to be if the listItemView is scrolled out or null, the view sets the new context into the lisItemView.

Comment: @777JonathanSum Hopefully my edited answer clarifies some of the things that still seem to confuse you.